# Clock in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, clock, trigonometry

I have done a clock in canvas, I am actually drawing lines on canvas from the center, for every second I draw a line from center in a circle, I am ending up with seconds line allover the clock. how do i clear the previously drawn line so that it looks like a real clock.

Help much appreciated thank you

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

for (i = 0; i < 360; i += 10) {
  ctx.moveTo(i + 5, 180);
  ctx.lineTo(i, 180);

}
for (i = 0; i < 360; i += 10) {
  ctx.moveTo(180, i + 5);
  ctx.lineTo(180, i);

}

ctx.stroke();

var iSin = 0,
  counterSin = 0,
  xSin = 180,
  ySin = 0;
var iCos = 0,
  counterCos = 0,
  xCos = 0,
  yCos = 180;
var iCircle = 0,
  counterCircle = 0,
  xCircle = 180,
  yCircle = 0;
var iLinesInCircle = 0,
  counterLinesInCircle = 0,
  xLinesInCircle = 180,
  yLinesInCircle = 0;
var iMinutes = 0,
  counterMinutes = 0,
  xMinutes = 180,
  yMinutes = 0;
var iHours = 0,
  counterHours = 0,
  xHours = 180,
  yHours = 0;
var increase = 90 / 180 * Math.PI / 9;
var increaseLinesInCircle = 6 * Math.PI / 180;
var increaseMinutes = 6 * Math.PI / 180;
var increaseHours = 6 * Math.PI / 180;
//drawSineWave();
//drawCosineWave();
//drawCircle();
drawLinesInCircle();
drawMinutes();
drawHours();

function drawSineWave() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = ("#0C620B");
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.moveTo(xSin, ySin);
  xSin = 180 + Math.sin(counterSin) * 180;
  ySin = iSin;
  counterSin += increase;
  ctx.lineTo(xSin, ySin);
  ctx.stroke();
  iSin += 10;
  if (iSin <= 360) {
    setTimeout(drawSineWave, 100);
  }
}


function drawCosineWave() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = ("#BE1616");
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.moveTo(xCos, yCos);
  xCos = iCos;
  yCos = 180 - Math.cos(counterCos) * 180;
  counterCos += increase;
  ctx.lineTo(xCos, yCos);
  ctx.stroke();
  iCos += 10;
  if (iCos <= 360) {
    setTimeout(drawCosineWave, 100);
  }
}

function drawCircle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = ("#021A02");
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.moveTo(xCircle, yCircle);
  xCircle = 180 + Math.sin(counterCircle) * 180;
  yCircle = 180 - Math.cos(counterCircle) * 180;
  counterCircle += increase;
  ctx.lineTo(xCircle, yCircle);
  ctx.stroke();
  iCircle += 10;
  if (iCircle <= 360) {
    setTimeout(drawCircle, 100);
  }
}

function drawLinesInCircle() {

  var ctxline = c.getContext("2d");
  //ctxline.restore();
  ctxline.beginPath();
  ctxline.strokeStyle = ("#EDDE54");
  ctxline.lineWidth = 1;
  ctxline.moveTo(180, 180);
  xLinesInCircle = 180 + Math.sin(counterLinesInCircle) * 180;
  yLinesInCircle = 180 - Math.cos(counterLinesInCircle) * 180;
  counterLinesInCircle += increaseLinesInCircle;
  ctxline.lineTo(xLinesInCircle, yLinesInCircle);
  ctxline.stroke();
  //ctxline.clearRect(0,0,360,360 );
  iLinesInCircle += 6;
  if (iLinesInCircle <= 360) {
    setTimeout(drawLinesInCircle, 1000);
  }
}

function drawMinutes() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = ("#545EED");
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.moveTo(180, 180);
  xMinutes = 180 + Math.sin(counterMinutes) * 160;
  yMinutes = 180 - Math.cos(counterMinutes) * 160;
  counterMinutes += increaseMinutes;
  ctx.lineTo(xMinutes, yMinutes);
  ctx.stroke();
  iMinutes += 6;
  if (iMinutes <= 360) {
    setTimeout(drawMinutes, 60000);
  }
}

function drawHours() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = ("#BE1616");
  ctx.lineWidth = 7;
  ctx.moveTo(180, 180);
  xHours = 180 + Math.sin(counterHours) * 120;
  yHours = 180 - Math.cos(counterHours) * 120;
  counterHours += increaseHours;
  ctx.lineTo(xHours, yHours);
  ctx.stroke();
  iHours += 6;
  if (iHours <= 360) {
    setTimeout(drawHours, 3600000);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="360" height="360" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Comment: Have you look of lots of example available for clock. Like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations and  http://www.kirupa.com/html5/create_an_analog_clock_using_the_canvas.htm etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be, probably, to first draw the same line in the backgroundcolor of the canvas, and then draw the next line.

Comment: Hi I tried that but dint work, i also tried using save and restore context, but it is not working. any idea? In the 31st line of fiddle if i clear the context it does not work too. http://jsfiddle.net/RaoBurugula/p5cdLg9v/1/

Comment: Look at my answer, you first have to save it then clear it. Then your script and then at last restore it. Please Let me now if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Have one global timeout which ticks along every second and increments a number of global variables which keep track of how many seconds, minutes and hours have elapsed.

Something conceptually like this... *(not tested)*

```
var second = 0;
var minute = 0;
var hour = 0;

setTimeout(tick, 1000);

function tick() {

    // Clear the canvas
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Draw the clock background or anything else first
    drawBackground();

    // Increment the seconds and check if a minute has been reached
    if (++second == 60) {

        // Increment the minutes and check if an hour has been reached
        if (++minute == 60) {

            // Increment the hours and check if it has reached 12 again
            if (++hours == 12) {
                hour = 0;
            }
            // Overlay the hour hand, using the hours variable
            drawHourHand(hour);

            // Reset the minute counter
            minute = 0;
        }

        // Overlay the minute hand, using the minutes variable
        drawMinuteHand(minute);

        // Reset the second counter
        second = 0;
    }

    // Overlay the second hand, using the seconds variable
    drawSecondHand(second);
}
```

You then have global control of your timings from one place, and each time the clock ticks you are redrawing the elements on the canvas in their new places.

You need to plug the timing variables into your drawing functions so that they are directly used to calculate the angle at which the hand should lie on the clock face.

```
function drawSecondHand(seconds) {
    var degrees = seconds * 6;
    // Convert to radians and draw your line, etc...
}
```

In the function above, you are calculating the degrees of the line angle using the seconds variable which is coming from your global timing.

```
1 second = 6 degrees
2 second = 12 degrees
3 second = 18 degrees
...
58 second = 348 degrees
59 second = 354 degrees
60 second (reset to 0 second) = 0 degrees
1 second = 6 degrees
2 second = 12 degrees
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an main function that calls every function in your script.
This function should clear everytime the screen.

For example:

```
/*

  Your script here

                   */

function draw() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);

    //draw
    drawSineWave();
    drawCircle();
    drawLinesInCircle()
    drawMinutes();
    drawHours();


    ctx.restore();
}
var animateInterval = setInterval(draw,0);
```

Let me know if this works for you